# PayPal IPNs suddenly stop flowing in

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have following problem: custom webshop, written in C#, hosted on Azure server with Windows Server 2019 Datacenter, regularly updated. There was integration with PayPal, working for several years. Suddenly, a few days ago, IPN messages stopped coming in. PayPal IPN history says "Error 500, Retrying". The problem is with PP sending message TO the endpoint - if we copy unsent IPN message from PP history and send it manually (from outside cloud) using sth like Postman all is ok: the message is properly received by our endpoint, sent to PP for verification, VERIFIED by PP, then processed etc.

I DID read other IPN-related questions, but found no situation like this.

Any ideas what could happen and what to do? Thank you in advance... :)

Answer (score 0):

Ask PayPal to check if your domain is blocked (marked as malware) by services like [Palo Alto Networks](https://urlfiltering.paloaltonetworks.com/query/), or DNS filter providers like OpenDNS, or ...

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately PayPal support is not so interested in helping (it's the "which answer would make you go?" style). 
Luckily we found that changing url of our IPN endpoint helped to solve the problem (at least for now).